# Floating point exception (core dumped) binomial coefficient

Tags: c

I am pretty new to coding so I have no idea whats wrong.

I am receiving the error "Floating point exception (core dumped)" in my code.

In this program I want to calculate the binomial coefficient without functions.

What am I doing wrong?

Some of it is in German, but I think the code should be self explaining.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n = 0;
  int nfak = 0;
  int k = 0;
  int kfak = 0;
  int differenzfak = 0;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int z = 0;
  int bk = 0;
  printf("n: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("k: ");
  scanf("%d", &k);

  if (k > n) {
    printf(
        "Bitte geben Sie für n eine Zahl größer gleich k, größer gleich Null ein.");
    return 0;
  }
  nfak = n;
  x = n - 1;

  while (x != 0) {
    nfak = nfak * x;
    x = x - 1;
  }

  printf("nfak=%d\n", nfak);

  kfak = k;
  y = k - 1;

  while (y != 0) {
    kfak = kfak * y;
    y = y - 1;
  }

  printf("kfak=%d\n", kfak);

  differenzfak = n - k;
  if (n - k == 0) {
    differenzfak = 1;
  } else {
    z = differenzfak - 1;

    while (z != 0) {
      differenzfak = differenzfak * z;
      z = z - 1;
    }
  }
  printf("differenzfak=%d\n", differenzfak);

  bk = (nfak / (kfak * differenzfak));

  printf("Binomialkoeffizient=%d\n", bk);
}
```

Comment: Note: `for()` loops exist for a reason.

Comment: Yes you are right, that would have been much easier. 
Still, why do I get the error?

Comment: Also: your `main()` function does not return anything. It should return an int value. (preferrably zero)

Comment: Ok thank you very much.
Do you know why I receive the error?

Comment: Your program returns some *random* result to its caller (the shell) The shell interprets this as your program's result/exit code. (it is actually a bit more complicated than this...) See the man pages for `exit()` and `wait()` BTW: I *think* that the falling out of main without a return was *fixed* by c99)

Comment: @Ferus It may seem like people are nitpicking irrelevant details, however these irrelevant details are important. 90% of the beginner [c] questions/problems are caused by not paying attention to small seemingly irrelevant details. Also I've watched someone spend hours debugging, because they refused to fix warnings, while addressing those warnings would have fixed their program.

Answer (score 0):

Canddiate:

Even though the message is "Floating point exception (core dumped) binomial coefficient
", `nfak/(kfak*differenzfak)` is doing a integer division by zero.

Either `kfak` or `differenzfak` is zero.

Suggest amending code to verify:

```
int product = kfak * differenzfak;
if (product == 0) {
  printf("Divide by Zero\n");
  bk= 0;
} else {
  bk= nfak / product;
}
```